# CSS: how come html, body height: 100% is more then 100%?

Tags: html, css, height, footer, sticky-footer

hey, i was trying to do a bottom sticky footer [link test](http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/) and but it kept being more then 100% meaning it scrolled a litle bit..

so i made a simple HTML code, without any additions but its still more than 100%, see here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="he" lang="he" dir="rtl" id="bangler">
    <head>
        <title>my title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #wrapper { height: 100%; }
        body > #wrapper { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">aa</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the thing is, it scrolls just a little bit more then 100% meaning about 5-10px more.. this is really strange, on both IE and Firefox !!

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of the default `body` margins. Add this to your styles:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure cross-browser compatibility to my websites, I **always** define the body margins myself. In this case: `html, body {margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; }`
I didn't realize that the body had it's own pre-defined margins and padding until I had learned quite a bit of CSS.

Comment: Please note that margin: 0 0 0 0; is a verbose syntax.

Comment: I agree, but I use it for quick adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Because `padding` and/or `margin` (depending on the browser) are non-zero for `html` and/or `body` by default, and padding and margin wrap around the content height.

Answer (score -1):

All browsers have their little quirks and they also slightly display selectors and attributes differently so what BoltClock answer is doing is just making sure that all browsers deal with start of with a margin of zero and a padding of zero.

If you do a search for CSS reset you will find more information about it.